# Emails dissappeared from user's exchange 2007 mailbox

Tags: email, exchange-2007, windows-sbs-2008

I have just completed a migration from SBS 2003 to SBS 2008 following the instructions in SBS_Migration.doc. The SBS 2008 was installed into VMWare for the flexibility, etc. Forefront was installed and it seemed to peg the guest at 100% CPU usage for hours on end. It was uninstalled this morning and the server rebooted, which has massively reduced CPU usage.

One of the users (of 6 in total) had logged into OWA before then (early in the morning) and then after the server was rebooted he had arrived in the office and fired up Outlook. All the emails that were delivered between Tuesday afternoon and the reboot had been removed from his mailbox. We can't find them anywhere. Both external and internal emails went walkabout. They are all in the message tracking tool. No other user appears to be affected, though they are much lower users of email. We use the POP3 connector because our ADSL is not reliable enough for a proper SMTP setup.

I've been Googling all day and haven't found any possible solutions. How can I get these emails back? Are there any steps I can take to prevent this happening in the future?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a backup of your exchange datafiles(!) and try to repair Exchange store with [eseutil](http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2004/06/18/159413.aspx) tool

Comment: I just did that any now I can't mount the mailbox database with the error:
Failed to mount database 'Mailbox Database'.

Mailbox Database
Failed
Error:
Exchange is unable to mount the database that you specified. Specified database: BLUE\First Storage Group\Mailbox Database; Error code: MapiExceptionJetErrorIndexNotFound: Unable to mount database. (hr=0x80004005, ec=-1404)
.

There is nothing on Google about this error and restoring the datafile backups produces the same error. I started doing this at 8am and it is now almost 5pm so the server has been unavailable all day. Boss is mad!!!

Comment: OK I restored from the "real" backup and at least it is mounting now. I don't know if the missing emails are back.